# I'm having some troubles understanding how pointers work in c

Tags: c

So I try to do the Heap Sort in C for a row of an 2d array
So basically I find the smallest sum of all the rows from the array and I try to sort the elements of that row, for that I'm trying to store the index of the smallest row with a pointer but when I use pointer the programm it's not returning the index but the adress

```
//funcion to find the smallest row sum
void min_rand(int(*a)[50], int n, int m, int *mi)
{
    int min_row = 0;
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        min_row += a[0][j];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int sum_row = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            sum_row += a[i][j];

        if (sum_row < min_row) {
            min_row = sum_row;
            *mi = i;
        }
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;

    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void heapify_c(int(*a)[50], int n, int i, int mi)
{
    int largest = i;
    int l = 2 *i + 1;
    int r = 2 *i + 2;

    if (l < n && a[mi][l] > a[mi][largest])
        largest = l;

    if (r < n && a[mi][r] > a[mi][largest])
        largest = r;

    if (largest != i) {
        swap(&a[mi][i], &a[mi][largest]);
        heapify_c(a, n, largest, mi);
    }
}

void heapSort_c(int(*a)[50], int n, int mi)
{
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify_c(a, n, i, mi);

    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        swap(&a[mi][0], &a[mi][i]);
        heapify_c(a, i, 0, mi);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[50][50];
    int n, m, mi;

    min_rand(a, n, m, &mi);
    heapSort_c(a, n, mi);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't print the sorted elements in the e.g. above but I just want to know if I'm doing something so terrebly wrong cause I did this before with counting sort and it worked without any problems

Comment: Please [edit] and format your code properly.

Comment: Proper indentation makes the code readable. You don't need to do it manually, just use online tools like [this](https://techiedelight.com/tools/clike)

Comment: `it's not returning the index but the adress` ... that's how pointers work! If you want the index you can subtract the *"base address"*: `int *pointer = &array[3] /* address of 4th element */; int index = pointer - array /* 3 = index of 4th element */;`

Comment: When coding functions or variables, try to give parameters or variables names that can explain there purpose, not just  n, m. And initialize variables that are passed by value to a function. Eg : n, m = (lineNumber, columnNumber?) are not initialized before calling min_rand .